# Convert tuple to string

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert `('nice', 'movement')` to `'nice movement'` in python.
I think join feature of tuple isn't appropriate because I want to add a space.

What could be a possible regex for it?

Answer (score 3):

You **do** use the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), by using a space to join with:

```
' '.join(yourtuple)
```

There is no `join` feature on tuples, and you cannot join sequences using regular expressions.

Demo:

```
>>> t = ('nice', 'movement')
>>> ' '.join(t)
'nice movement'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use `str.join`, then you could do a `functools.reduce`:

```
In [31]: import functools

In [32]: tup = ('nice', 'movement')

In [33]: functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+" "+y, tup)
Out[33]: 'nice movement'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join attribute of string (single space or any delimiter you want) with any iterable like a tuple or list of strings.

```
In [5]: ' '.join(('hello','world'))
Out[5]: 'hello world'
```

Works for Python 2 and 3 (tried 2.5 and 3.4).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific context, the `%` operator may be appropriate as well:

```
t=("nice","movement")
print "%s %s" % t
```